# Symfony2 Elasticsearch search with and without special characters

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, elasticsearch, query-builder

I am making a search form for products in a spanish shop. There are no translations(and there shouldnt be in the future), only spanish language... However, while the texts should be displayed in spanish, people ussualy search in english...

What I mean is:

```
Product name is                : Sofá
But people ussualy search like : Sofa
```

This ofcourse does not work so easily with elasticsearch... If i type Sofá in search it works, simple sofa finds nothing...

One solution is to create more fields in database... for texts without special characters... But this is not the solution owners want... Is there any other way to do this? For search I use my own query:

```
public function findProductsBySearch($data)
{

    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('o');
    $qb->addSelect('trans')->join('o.translations', 'trans');
    $qb->addSelect('gallery')->join('o.gallery', 'gallery');
    $qb->addSelect('media')->join('gallery.galleryHasMedias', 'media');
    $qb->addSelect('image')->join('media.media', 'image');
    $qb->andWhere("LOWER(o.adminTitle) LIKE :name");
    $qb->orderBy("o.base", 'ASC');
    $qb->SetParameter('name', '%'.strtolower($data).'%');
    return $qb;

}
```

but this returns 0 too:

```
{
"query": {
"bool": {
"must": [
{
"term": {
"adminTitle": "sofa"
}
}
],
"must_not": [ ],
"should": [ ]
}
},
"from": 0,
"size": 10,
"sort": [ ],
"aggs": { }
}
```

Comment: Heum.. What is your dbms ? In MySQL no difference is made between "é" and "e". I think it is Doctrine2 which is making a difference. Have you tried with a native query ?

Comment: Try installing ICU plugin into elasticsearch, it handles special characters. But I dont really understand, why would owner tell you not to add a new field to your mapping - its a common way to achieve something like this (you can then omit that field when searching - there are two ways: with **field** attribute and with **_source** one). And at least, if you are dealing with english, its not only about special characters, but its completely translated different translation, isnt it?

Comment: EDIT : In MySQL no difference (in **utf8_general_ci**) is made between "é" and "e"

Comment: @Delphine He is not using MySQL...

Comment: @WaxCage I didn't notice that in his post.. Whatever, it could be useful to know that for others who are approximatly in the same case